# could not get the full image in wia scanner in c# windows application

Tags: c#

I am using a code  for wia scanner. but after 75dpi the scanner does not give me full Image. I am getting only the half image from the scanner .please check this out.

```
    private static void SaveImageToPNGFile(ImageFile image, string fileName)
    {
        ImageProcess imgProcess = new ImageProcess();
        object convertFilter = "Convert";
        string convertFilterID = imgProcess.FilterInfos.get_Item(ref convertFilter).FilterID;
        imgProcess.Filters.Add(convertFilterID, 0);
        SetWIAProperty(imgProcess.Filters[imgProcess.Filters.Count].Properties, "FormatID", WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatPNG);
        image = imgProcess.Apply(image);
        image.SaveFile(fileName);
    }
    private static void AdjustScannerSettings(IItem scannnerItem, int scanColor,
        int scanWidthPixels, int scanHeightPixels, int brightnessPercents, int contrastPercents)
    {

        SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, "4104", 24);
        SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, "6146", scanColor);
        SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, "6147", 75);//Horizontal resolution
        SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, "6148", 75);//vertical resolution

        SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, "6151", scanHeightPixels);
        SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, "6152", scanWidthPixels);
        SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, "6154", brightnessPercents);//range from -100 to 100. 0 refer for the normal brightnes
        SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, "6155", contrastPercents);//range from -100 to 100. 0 refer for the normal brightnes
    }
    private static void SetWIAProperty(IProperties properties, object propName, object propValue)
    {
        Property prop = properties.get_Item(ref propName);
        prop.set_Value(ref propValue);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int height = int.Parse(textBoxheight.Text.Trim());
        int width = int.Parse(textBoxwidth.Text.Trim());

        CommonDialogClass commonDialogClass = new CommonDialogClass();
        Device scannerDevice;
        try
        {

            scannerDevice = commonDialogClass.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, false , false);
            if (scannerDevice != null)
            {

                Item scannnerItem = scannerDevice.Items[1];
                AdjustScannerSettings(scannnerItem, 4, height, width, 20, 20);//dpi valid only for 150,200,300,400
                object scanResult = commonDialogClass.ShowTransfer(scannnerItem, WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatPNG, false);
                if (scanResult != null)
                {
                    ImageFile image = (ImageFile)scanResult;
                    // Image objimg = (Image)image;
                    string fileName = Path.GetTempPath() + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-fffffff") + ".png";
                    SaveImageToPNGFile(image, fileName);
                    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = fileName;
                    //pictureBox1.Height = height;
                    //pictureBox1.Width = width;
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
                    Bitmap obj = new Bitmap(fileName);
                    panel1.BackgroundImage = obj;
                    panel1.AutoSize = true;
                    panel1.AutoScroll = true;


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        wiascan obj = new wiascan();
        obj.Show();
    }
}
```

I tried in both in a pic box and  a panel to show my Image but both control could not give me the full image.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WIA;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Find a device.
            var deviceManager = new DeviceManager();
            var device = deviceManager.DeviceInfos[1].Connect();
            var item = device.Items[1];

            // Check if device exist.
            if(item == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Scanner not found!", "Status");
                return;
            }

            // Set the properties of the device.
            setItem(item, "6146", 1); // <- 4 black and white, 2 grayscale, 1 color, 0 unspecified.
            setItem(item, "6147", 200); // <- Horizontal resolution.
            setItem(item, "6148", 200); // <- Veritcal resolution.
            setItem(item, "6151", 200 * 8.5); // <- Horizontal scanning area.
            setItem(item, "6152", 200 * 11); // <- Vertical scanning area.
            setItem(item, "6149", 0); // <- Horizontal pixel start.
            setItem(item, "6150", 0); // <- Vertical pixel start.
            var properties = item.Properties;

            // Scan.
            var imageFile = (ImageFile)item.Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}");

            // Use to compress jpeg.
            WIA.ImageProcess myip = new WIA.ImageProcess();  
            myip.Filters.Add(myip.FilterInfos["Convert"].FilterID);
            myip.Filters[1].Properties["FormatID"].set_Value("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}");
            myip.Filters[1].Properties["Quality"].set_Value(99);
            
            // Create image an apply our image with the filter.
            ImageFile image = myip.Apply(imageFile);

            // Save to a given path.
            var path = "image.jpg";
            image.SaveFile(path);
            MessageBox.Show("Scan complete", "Status");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Status");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set scanner properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    static void setItem(IItem item, object property, object value)
    {
        Property aProperty = item.Properties.get_Item(ref property);
        aProperty.set_Value(ref value);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).